# How does edit.exe work?

Tags: user-interface, editor, dos

There is an exe in system32 called edit.com . It is an old text editor. I'm wondering how they made a console app have a gui, and work with the mouse? Thanks

Comment: Old-school DOS programming, I would say.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an app like this with VC++?

Comment: *LOL* I didn't know, that this program still exists in Vista!

Comment: cool, didn't know edit.com was still included! BTW edit.com is a com, not an exe, there's quite a difference ;-)

Comment: I wrote exe so people wouldn't think im trying to advertise a web site

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: edit.com is a "special" .com file: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/24/8332730.aspx It's actually an .exe with a .com extension (see the `MZ` header).

Comment: @ZoogieZork: weird! thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no shortcuts.
The mouse had to be interfaced with through assembly code.
You would call interrupt 33 to have access to several functions like reading the mouse motion counters and button states. Then you'd read the CPU registers to get those numbers. From there on you could do everything else in C, including the GUI-like interface. There's no shortcut to that either - it must be manually done, each individual square has to be painted the correct color.

Comment: Wow that sounded hard! Thanks for the info!

Comment: Wow ... looking up `int 33` leads to HTML copies of HELPPC. A tremendously useful TSR application that was a hyperlinked documentation system of the most common interrupts and other system-level stuff useful when writing that kind of code. A funny trip down the memory lane!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't want to do it with a very good documentation by my side that I could reference. :) I'm new here so I don't know if we can share links, but if you search for "INT 33,1 Show Mouse Cursor" you'll find some reference material about all the functions and a bit about how they were used.

Comment: ... and writing into the text video buffer via `B800:0000`.  Back then, it was "fun".

Answer (score 0):

edit.com is REALLY old.  It was written before the Windows GUI was really popular.  They probably use special DOS functions to create the graphics and recognize the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Well prior to Windows 3.1 there used to be an operating system call DOS and I believe the mouse thing came with DOS 5.0 or DOS 4.0.

Comment: Mouse drivers could be used well before DOS 4.0 (I personally accessed one programmatically in DOS 3.3).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for adding mouse and color support to a console is to use some kind of TextArea control and make your own console instead of using the DOS console.  You could also look into [ncurses](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm) for Windows but I don't recommend it.  If you just want color you could also look at this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/console_apps__colour_text.aspx).